# Checking that an object exists in DB (Django)

Tags: python, django, transactions, referential-integrity

Consider this Django code:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=_("Name"), help_text='User Name', max_length=256)

class UsersGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_("Name"), help_text='Users Group Name', max_length=256)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

# ...

with transaction.atomic():
    group.users.add(user)
```

What if the user was deleted from the DB before the transaction starts? It would add an nonexistent user to `group.users`. This is an error.

What to do in this situation to preserve DB integrity?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Users are added through a Web interface. I don't understand you: How is this related with the way users are added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user does not exist while adding into groups then the query will fail in database raising IntegrityError with message as follows:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "app1_usersgroup_users" violates foreign key constraint "app1_usersgroup_users_user_id_96d48fc7_fk_polls_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(3) is not present in table "polls_user".
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just add the get in the `transaction.atomic` block:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    user = User.objects.get(name='stackoverflow')
    group.users.add(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exceptions to handle it as well:

```
    try:
      group.users.add(User.objects.get(name='Julian'))
    except:
      # handle the error - user doesn't exist
```